# AWS Step Function vs Lambda

Tags: parallel-processing, aws-lambda, amazon-swf, aws-step-functions

I have a use case to call an activity, on the response of the activity run parallel executions with different configs returning different values.

1. Call Activity : Output -> MasterObject
2. Run parallel threads

   - Thread 1 : Transform MasterObject -> Object1, then publish to queue1
   - Thread 2 : Transform MasterObject -> Object2, then publish to queue2
   - Thread 3 : Transform MasterObject -> Object3, then publish to queue3

This can be achieved by using step functions : activity worker + lambdas.
My question is do I even need step functions for it, shouldnt only lambdas suffice?

Basically does this processing even require a state machine?

Comment: no. you could just trigger multiple lambdas on the same trigger, each running the transform independently and publishing the result to different queue. state machines are good for handling errors, flow control and such.

Comment: @grepe You should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @MatthewPope i would, but answers that can fit into a single word tend to be removed by overzealous moderators.